# Can you appeal a closed answer?

Tags: discussion

I posted an answer on the Electrical Engineering Stack overflow that did 2 things: It provided resistor values for a circuit that I found worked, and it added a follow-on question. I guess adding a follow-on is bad form. Fine. I removed that part of my "answer". I think the remainder of my answer is useful and should be un-deleted. How do I request that it be un-deleted? It was deleted by a moderator, so I can't vote to un-delet it myself.

Here is the original thread:

[How to invert a digital signal](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/30238/how-to-invert-a-digital-signal)

Since my question is deleted, you might not be able to see my answer unless you're a moderator though.

Comment: OK, since you edited your post to turn it into just an answer, it can be "undeleted". We'll let the community decide on its overall merits.

Comment: Thank you sir. Isn't deleting my answer (which contained what I thought was useful information) for also containing a question a bit draconian?

Comment: Perhaps, but we get a lot of that ([newcomers answering old questions](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/q/3744/11683)), and we like to stay on top of it. If the answer does not clearly add materially to what has already been said, we tend to clean it up. Yours was cluttered with a secondary question, which seemed to be the main point of your post. Asking a question within an answer really doesn't work on SE.

Comment: @DuncanC Draconian is the best way to describe the anti-newbie sentiment around here

Comment: @Passerby, I get that feeling. I'm not an EE, but I am a self-directed learner who's willing to roll up my sleeves and work to learn new skills.  I am an active participant on several software forums, so I know how annoying lazy "develop a full solution for me based on a vague description" type questions can be. I try not to ask sloppy, poorly formed questions.

Comment: You have a ton of rep of SO, so you clearly get how this system works. Why would you post another question as an answer in the first place?

Comment: @MattYoung, It was a mistake. I decided to post additional information about the resistor values that I worked out for the specified circuit. While I was at it, I mused about something that was puzzling me. Clearly I won't be doing that again...

Comment: If you don't want your answers deleted, don't write bad answers.  You should know better than to ask a new question in a answer.  The system, doesn't, nor should it, be careful when taking out the trash.  You can't expect the volunteers here to dissect all bad answers to remove the bad parts and keep the good.  They delete the whole mess and move on.  After all, the answer as a whole is bad.  It's nobody's job but yours to fix that.  Again, if you don't want stuff like this happening to you, follow the rules.  I don't really care how someone that can't follow the rules gets mistreaded.

Comment: Jeez dude, calm down. I acknowledged my mistake and corrected it, and as stated before, won't make the same mistake again. I am sorry if my violation of the rules has upset you.

Answer (score 2):

Just to provide a direct answer to your question you can always flag your own answers for diamond moderator attention, just trying it appears to be the only flagging option for your own answers which is probably understandable:

[image: Own answer flagging options]

Being an experienced Stack Overflow user you seem to have identified the additional question in an answer that led to the confusion. You could have used that option and paraphrasing your edit summary maybe something like "Please re-consider the deletion, I've removed question-in-answer and changed post to emphasize extra info I provided in my answer".

In my experience the moderators here are helpful and always attend to such flags, but if you're not satisfied with their response or the flag is declined you can always bring it up on a meta post as you've done. But normally as an initial step a flag is the quickest and easiest way there because at the end of the day a moderator will need to undelete  it.

For viewing deleted answers the rules are the same as other Stack Exchange sites where users with 10k+  reputation can view them. So if you have a question regarding something deleted in the future where you'd like wider coverage it's probably worth quoting it so everyone can see it.

Comment: Peter, thanks for the thorough response. I'll take a look at flagging in case this comes up in the future. The EE board is much more tightly managed than the SO board. I apparently need to fine-tune my posting style.

Comment: I accepted and up-voted your answer yesterday. (Thanks) Now I see the vote count is zero. Did somebody else down-vote you? I  guess I don't have enough rep yet on this site to tell.